Switch to a different boto3 version in the same Python session
May I ask if an old version of boto3 is already imported, how to switch to a new version in the same Python script?
I tried the following approach but didn't work:
import sys
import importlib

import boto3
print(boto3.__version__)  # prints 1.16.57

# unload boto3
del sys.modules['boto3']

# unload all of its dependencies
boto3_dependencies = ['botocore', 'jmespath', 's3transfer', 'python_dateutil', 'six', 'urllib3']
for d in boto3_dependencies:
  if d in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules[d]

# invalidate cache
importlib.invalidate_caches()

sys.path.insert(0, /path/to/a/newer/boto3/version)

import boto3
import botocore
print(boto3.__version__)  # prints 1.34.137
print(botocore.__version__)  # prints 1.34.162

boto3.client(service_name='bedrock-runtime')
# throws exception:
# botocore.exception.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'bedrock-runtime'

Even if the newer version of boto3 (1.34.137) and botocore (1.34.162) is loaded, it still complains bedrock-runtime is unknown.
This problem would not occur if the old boto3 version was not imported. However it is not easy to change our setup. An older version always needs to be imported. So a workaround that allow switching to a different boto3 version during runtime would be super helpful.
Appreciate any help/advice!

are you able to run the processes separately/conditionally? if so, you could move the boto3/botocore dependencies to a different requirements.txt or pyproject.toml and install the specific version for the different code. It may be simpler to configure the environment correctly than to mess around with imports at runtime.

@r_2009, thank you. Haha unfortunately we are dealing with an urgent deadline but our infra has other priorities at this time. It would be great if we can find a solution ourselves in the runtime.
Appreciate your comment!

cool cool; for the import boto3 the 2nd time, I'm not sure it'll make a difference, but you could try https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module
another thought is executing the code in a subprocess so you can configure the system path before any other code is executed
